# How to return all weekdays in a range of dates, sorted in ascending order

Tags: python, weekday

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

#this is the start day
day = input()
#this is number of days input
num=int(input())
#this is the start date of the shipment
temp = input()
#this is the date format the string into a day using the strptime object
start_day = datetime.strptime(day, '%A')
#this line will format the string input into a date
format1 = datetime.strptime(temp, '%d-%m-%Y')
#this line will add number input onto the date
arrival = format1 + timedelta(days=num)

for i in range(num):
    a = arrival - timedelta(days=i)
    if a.weekday() <5 :        
        print(a.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
```

The above code gives me three weekday dates but I am expecting four.

This is my output:

```
05-03-2019
04-03-2019
01-03-2019
```

but I need this:

```
01-03-2019
04-03-2019
05-03-2019
06-03-2019
```

All dates starting with the oldest first e.g. ascending order.

Here is the assignment I have:

> Radan Logistics is a mid sized Shipping Company known for its Customer oriented delivery services. The Company Management intended to place an information kiosk in their Head Office which would help their Customers to fetch all the desired information with regards to their shipment. One such vital information that Customers would prefer to know is the details of the working days of the Company which would help them track their shipments.
>
> Help the Management write a program for the kiosk, that when given the start day, number of days 'n' and the start date, will output the dates of the 'n' business days (excluding Saturday and Sunday).

Input Format:

- The first line of input is a String, the start day.
- The second line of the input is the number of days.
- Third line is a string that correponds to the start date of the shipment.

Output Format:

Output is list of dates of *n* working days separated by new line.

Sample Input 1:

```
Monday
7
03-12-2007
```

Sample Output 1:

```
04-12-2007
05-12-2007
06-12-2007
07-12-2007
10-12-2007
11-12-2007
```

Sample Input 2:

```
Thursday
10
25-02-2012
```

Sample Output 2:

```
26-02-2012
29-02-2012
01-03-2012
02-03-2012
03-03-2012
04-03-2012
07-03-2012
08-03-2012
09-03-2012
```

Comment: What is the input?

Comment: isn't your desired output ascending then? 01 is before 04?

Comment: apologies Paul you're right thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, please have a look on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In the title you want a descending order, in the body ascending, .... and now you add a picture (which is quite unreadable). Please take a while to understand what you want the program to do. Some info for [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (avoid the `ìnput`s)

Comment: you welcome me to the space cards and then make me feel like a pleb for getting something wrong - please try and be constructive, I would assume there is scope for users with varying coding abilities on this forum? Anyhoo the image I put on the question is readable if you can zoom in on your browser - if can't do that then you can't help me, which is fine for me.

Comment: Writing a good question is not such an easy task as it looks like... it takes experience. But there are some standards that should be satisfied, see for ex previous links. And this has nothing to do with code skills... I am very happy to give some help. SO has its politic on pictures (avoid them). Notice that the output in the assignment is a list but in your code there is not trace of lists... how should be understood it? Questions with ambiguities give raise to confusion and my  previous comment only meant to point this out

Comment: @cards please note that on this ask I am getting the output I need except for 1 date, the help I have had from Mohamed and Kyle have me on the right tracks now, hence my comments below. The output I am getting now is in the right ascending order, I am just missing 1 date now, I am getting 28-02-2019 instead of 06-03-2019. I note your comments regarding pictures, surely if SO would hide the images feature if they weren't keen? I can't see how my image has caused a problem? Whilst I appreciate your help, you are under no obligation to help me.

Comment: a question should be standalone, image only for support (as mentioned by  
9769953)

Comment: okay I took out the image and replaced it with text for those who cannot use a zoom feature embedded in most web browsers.

Comment: (If the Company is really from Germany, Program and Kiosk are also Nouns which should use upper Case.)

Comment: But what is *your* input?

Comment: @John Alderton the 2nd output either seems wrong or I haven't just understood the problem. `25-02-2012` is a Saturday so a **non** working day... and your output start from 26 (a Sunday) which is non-sense to me. Furthermore... why is needed the 1st input, the day name?

Comment: Hello @9769953 - sadly the assignment does not specifically request a date value, therefore it has to be programmed based on whatever is provided. The assignment requests that the first value entered will be converted to a day, hence day = input() and then start_day = datetime.strptime(day, '%A') later on , second value is number of days hence num=int(input()) as integer, 3rd value is formatting start date value entered into DD-MM-YYYY format hence temp = input() then format1 = datetime.strptime(temp, '%d-%m-%Y') later on. The code I have right now returns dates correctly but missing one date

Comment: Ok. So what do you type at the three input prompts?

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be that you're looping through an ascending range of numbers, but that number is subtracted to get the result. For example 10-1=9, 10-2=8, 10-3=7, etc. You can instead loop through range(num) in descending order. Also, range() by default goes from index zero up to and not including num. To have num included, you may want range(num + 1)

```
for i in reversed(range(num + 1)):
    a = arrival - timedelta(days=i)
    if a.weekday() <5 :        
        print(a.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Kyle Alm - I now get this:                                                                                                                          
28-02-2019                                                                                                                        
01-03-2019
04-03-2019
05-03-2019                                                                                                                             but actually I need 06-03-2019 in the output

Comment: It's a little unclear - I don't fully understand the difference between 'temp' and 'day', and 'day' is unused, you derive 'start_day' from it, but that's it. It could be, again, from how you are dealing with 'num', specifically in defining 'arrival'. Try:

arrival = format1 + timedelta(days=num+1)

Answer (score 0):

To show 5 days you  have to make `a.weekday() <=5`  not `num+1`
and add `reversed` to range to reverse the showing of data

```
for i in reversed(range(num)):
    a = arrival - timedelta(days=i)
    if a.weekday() <=5 :        
        print(a.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Mohamed - your help has resolved the a order issue, in the output I now get this:                                                                                                                          
01-03-2019
04-03-2019
05-03-2019 but the 06-03-2019 date is missing

Comment: @JohnAlderton  provide the input to your code in the question to better solving the problem

Comment: your help Mohamed along with Kyle has solved the sort issue, Kyle I think is on to something with sum+1 approach but its added to the backwards date rather than 06-03-2019

Comment: hi @9769953 sadly for the exercise I am doing I cannot provide an input, the task is requesting that the data input is formatted as a date I will share the task on here so that you guys have some context

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

start = '01-03-2019'
num_days = 7

date_list = [datetime.datetime.strptime(start, "%d-%m-%Y") + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(num_days)]
list_of_weekdays = [day.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') for day in date_list if day.isoweekday() in range(1, 6)]

[print(day) for day in list_of_weekdays[::-1]]
```

Comment: Thanks Paul for coming back to me, the other answers are on the right lines for me, the task I am working sadly does not require a specific date, it more deals with the data entered, reformats that as a date and then adds the integer to it, its the last bit which is the problem now. The expected output is supposed to include 06-03-2019 and this is the one date that is missing

Answer (score 0):

Print range of dates in descending order, i.e. from newest to oldest.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def range_of_dates_from_interval(start, end, date_format='%d-%m-%Y'):
    start_date = datetime.strptime(start, date_format).date()
    end_date = datetime.strptime(end, date_format).date()

    d = timedelta(days=1)

    date = end_date
    while date != start_date:
        print(date.strftime(date_format))
        date -= d
    print(date.strftime(date_format))


def range_of_dates_with_step(start, amount_days, date_format='%d-%m-%Y'):
    start_date = datetime.strptime(start, date_format).date()
    d = timedelta(days=1)
    for i in range(amount_days-1, -1, -1):
        print((start_date + d*i).strftime(date_format))


date_format = '%d-%m-%Y'

# test first function
start = '29-03-2019'
end = '02-04-2019'

range_of_dates_from_interval(start, end, date_format=date_format)
#02-04-2019
#01-04-2019
#31-03-2019
#30-03-2019
#29-03-2019


# test second function
start = '29-03-2019'
amount_days = 5

range_of_dates_with_step(start, amount_days, date_format=date_format)
#02-04-2019
#01-04-2019
#31-03-2019
#30-03-2019
#29-03-2019
```

---

EDIT: answer of the assignment

```
import datetime

# not needed but useful for display information
def weekdays_iso(day_num_format=True) -> dict:
    out = {}
    d0 = datetime.date.fromordinal(1)   # day zero
    d, a_day = d0, datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    for i in range(7):
        if day_num_format:
            out[d.strftime("%A")] = i+1
        else:
            out[i+1] = d.strftime("%A")
        d += a_day
    return out

# main function
def get_business_days(num_b_days, start, date_format='%d-%m-%Y') -> list:
    b_days = []
    start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, date_format).date()
    b_day, a_day = start_date, datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    while num_b_days > 1:
        b_day += a_day
        if b_day.isoweekday() not in {6, 7}: 
            b_days.append(b_day)
            num_b_days -= 1
    
    return b_days


WEEKDAYS_ISO = weekdays_iso(day_num_format=False)
date_format = '%d-%m-%Y'
```

Test 1

```
start = "03-12-2007"
n_b_days = 7

# result
b_days = get_business_days(n_b_days, start, date_format=date_format)

# check
for d in b_days:
   print(d.strftime(date_format), WEEKDAYS_ISO[d.isoweekday()])
```

Output 1:

```
04-12-2007 Tuesday
05-12-2007 Wednesday
06-12-2007 Thursday
07-12-2007 Friday
10-12-2007 Monday
11-12-2007 Tuesday
```

Test 2

```
start = "25-02-2012"
n_b_days = 10

# result
b_days = get_business_days(n_b_days, start, date_format=date_format)

# check
for d in b_days:
   print(d.strftime(date_format), WEEKDAYS_ISO[d.isoweekday()])
```

Output 2:

```
27-02-2012 Monday
28-02-2012 Tuesday
29-02-2012 Wednesday
01-03-2012 Thursday
02-03-2012 Friday
05-03-2012 Monday
06-03-2012 Tuesday
07-03-2012 Wednesday
08-03-2012 Thursday
```

Comment: some perplexity about the assignment, parameter day's name not used